# how to pause and unpause node object stream while processing its output

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, stream

I'm currently processing a file stream line by line by running it through a transform stream that emits `'line'` events. I would like to be able to, upon finding that the current line matches some criteria, pause the input file stream, start processing a new stream, and when that is finished, resume processing the original stream line by line. I've condensed it down to a minimal example below:

test.coffee:

```
fs = require 'fs'    
TestTransform = require './test-transform'
inStream = new TestTransform
fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(inStream)
inStream.on 'line', (line) ->
  process.stdout.write "-->"
  if line.match /line\.match/g
    process.stdout.write line
    console.error "PAUSE"
    inStream.pause()
    fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(process.stdout).on 'end', ->
      console.error "UNPAUSE"
      inStream.resume()
  else
    process.stdout.write line
```

test-transform.coffee:

```
Transform = require('stream').Transform

module.exports =
class TestTransform extends Transform
  constructor: ->
    Transform.call @, readableObjectMode: true
    @buffer = ""

  pushLines: ->
    newlineIndex = @buffer.indexOf "\n"
    while newlineIndex isnt -1
      @push @buffer.substr(0, newlineIndex + 1)
      @emit 'line', @buffer.substr(0, newlineIndex + 1)
      @buffer = @buffer.substr(newlineIndex + 1)
      newlineIndex = @buffer.indexOf "\n"

  _transform: (chunk, enc, cb) ->
    @buffer = @buffer + chunk.toString()
    @pushLines()
    cb?()

  _flush: (cb) ->
    @pushLines()
    @buffer += "\n"             # ending newline
    @push @buffer
    @emit 'line', @buffer       # push last line
    @buffer = ""
    cb?()
```

(Don't worry about the Transform stream too much, it's just an example.) Anyway, the output of `coffee test.coffee` looks like:

```
-->fs = require 'fs'
-->
-->TestTransform = require './test-transform'
-->
-->inStream = new TestTransform
-->
-->fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(inStream)
-->
-->inStream.on 'line', (line) ->
-->  process.stdout.write "-->"
-->  if line.match /line\.match/g
PAUSE
-->    process.stdout.write line
-->    console.error "PAUSE"
-->    inStream.pause()
-->    fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(process.stdout).on 'end', ->
-->      console.error "UNPAUSE"
-->      inStream.unpause()
-->  else
-->    process.stdout.write line
-->
fs = require 'fs'

TestTransform = require './test-transform'

inStream = new TestTransform

fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(inStream)

inStream.on 'line', (line) ->
  process.stdout.write "-->"
  if line.match /line\.match/g
    process.stdout.write line
    console.error "PAUSE"
    inStream.pause()
    fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(process.stdout).on 'end', ->
      console.error "UNPAUSE"
      inStream.unpause()
  else
    process.stdout.write line
```

So obviously, the pipe isn't getting paused, it's just continuing until finished (even though the `PAUSE` is getting run just as expected), and since `"UNPAUSE"` is never getting written out either, the `'end'` callback is never firing. Switching the stream to pause/unpause to the readStream from the transform stream doesn't seem to work either. I'm assuming from this behavior that node streams somehow don't respect pause/unpause from within an event callback.

There may also be another way to accomplish this without calling pause/unpause; if there's some way to like await the end of a stream and pause the current thread of execution, that'd effectively do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Do you have to complete processing before you start reading the stream again? Is it not sufficient to start the new processing job and continue reading from the stream? Node is good at doing thing asynchronously.

Comment: @Interrobang yeah, I'm trying to pipe both input streams to the same output stream and it's important that the second stream is entirely read to the output before the rest of the first one is input. I don't want the two streams interspersed in the output.

Comment: If it's sufficient to not have them interspersed you can use a buffer-style stream like [`concat-stream`](https://github.com/maxogden/concat-stream). Otherwise you need an abstraction on top of streams. One interesting way could be to use something like [Dust.js](http://www.dustjs.com/), which can natively interleave streams.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that. Since I don't expect to be dealing with streams gigabytes in length, I could conceivably pipe it all into a buffer and then process it whenever the other stream is done. I'd prefer to not have to hold the entire stream in memory all at once, though. I'll take a look at dust, I haven't seen that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, here's a simple Node app using [Dust.js](http://www.dustjs.com/) that solves the problem.

Dust is a templating engine, but one of its best features is its native understanding of Node Streams. This example uses Dust 2.7.0.

I'm using [`node-byline`](https://github.com/jahewson/node-byline) as a replacement for your Transform stream, but it does the same thing-- reads streams by line.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    byline = require('byline'),
    dust = require('dustjs-linkedin');

var stream = byline(fs.createReadStream('./test.txt', { encoding: 'utf8' }));

var template = dust.loadSource(dust.compile('{#byline}--> {.|s}{~n}{match}{/byline}'));

dust.stream(template, {
  byline: stream,
  match: function(chunk, context) {
    var currentLine = context.current();

    if(currentLine.match(/line\.match/g)) {
      return fs.createReadStream('./test.txt', 'utf8');
    }
    return chunk;
  }
}).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Here's the output from my program:

```
$ node index.js
--> fs = require 'fs'
--> TestTransform = require './test-transform'
--> inStream = new TestTransform
--> fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(inStream)
--> inStream.on 'line', (line) ->
-->   process.stdout.write "-->"
-->   if line.match /line\.match/g
fs = require 'fs'
TestTransform = require './test-transform'
inStream = new TestTransform
fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(inStream)
inStream.on 'line', (line) ->
  process.stdout.write "-->"
  if line.match /line\.match/g
    process.stdout.write line
    console.error "PAUSE"
    inStream.pause()
    fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(process.stdout).on 'end', ->
      console.error "UNPAUSE"
      inStream.resume()
  else
    process.stdout.write line

-->     process.stdout.write line
-->     console.error "PAUSE"
-->     inStream.pause()
-->     fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(process.stdout).on 'end', ->
-->       console.error "UNPAUSE"
-->       inStream.resume()
-->   else
-->     process.stdout.write line
```

As you can see, it's properly interleaved the output. If I can elaborate further on how the Dust part works, let me know.

**EDIT:** Here's an explanation of the Dust template specifically.

```
{#byline} {! look for the context variable named `byline` !}
{! okay, it's a stream. For each `data` event, output this stuff once !}
-->
{.|s} {! output the current `data`. Use |s to turn off HTML escaping !}
{~n} {! a newline !}
{match} {! look up the variable called `match` !}
{! okay, it's a function. Run it and insert the result !}
{! if the result is a stream, stream it in. !}
{/byline} {! done looping !}
```

Comment: This seems to make sense! (after reading through the dust syntax lol) I was looking for a solution without external dependencies, but this seems pretty lightweight.

In the match function given to dust.stream, why is the line `if line.match /line\.match/g` written out? It seems like dust would just return the fs.createReadStream instead of the chunk itself, and that line would be lost.

Comment: The match function is called once per line using `{#match/}`. If the current line (`context.current()`) matches, then the function streams in the contents of `test.txt`. If not, it just returns the current `chunk`, which allows the stream to continue.

Comment: That makes sense. What is the `{.|s}` part about in the template string? I assume that's telling it to read from the "stream" attribute (which starts with s), or just any attribute if stream doesn't exist, but that could be totally off base.

Comment: `{.}` means "current context", and `|s` means "don't HTML-escape".

Comment: I updated the answer with a more thorough explanation of the template.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a separate answer to this too; not as pretty, but also works.

Essentially, `pause()` only pauses output from a piped stream (in "flowing" mode); since I was listening to the `'line'` event, it wasn't flowing, and so `pause` of course did nothing. So the first solution was to use `removeListener` instead of `pause`, which does effectively stop the streaming. The file now looks like:

```
fs = require 'fs'
TestTransform = require './test-transform'
inStream = new TestTransform
fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(inStream)
c = (line) ->
  process.stdout.write "-->"
  if line.match /line\.match/g
    process.stdout.write line
    console.error "PAUSE"
    inStream.removeListener 'line', c
    f = fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee")
    f.on 'end', ->
      console.error "UNPAUSE"
      inStream.on 'line', c
    f.pipe(process.stdout)
  else
    process.stdout.write line
inStream.on 'line', c
```

And this produces output that *almost* works:

```
-->fs = require 'fs'
-->TestTransform = require './test-transform'
-->inStream = new TestTransform
-->fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(inStream)
-->c = (line) ->
-->  process.stdout.write "-->"
-->  if line.match /line\.match/g
PAUSE
fs = require 'fs'
TestTransform = require './test-transform'
inStream = new TestTransform
fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(inStream)
c = (line) ->
  process.stdout.write "-->"
  if line.match /line\.match/g
    process.stdout.write line
    console.error "PAUSE"
    inStream.removeListener 'line', c
    f = fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee")
    f.on 'end', ->
      console.error "UNPAUSE"
      inStream.on 'line', c
    f.pipe(process.stdout)
  else
    process.stdout.write line
inStream.on 'line', c
UNPAUSE
```

However, it looks like the original readable stream just stopped when I removed the listener; this makes some twisted sort of sense (I guess node garbage collects its readable streams when all listeners have been removed). So the final working solution that I found relies instead on piping. Since the Transform stream I showed above also pushes its output by line to any `'data'` listeners, `pause()` can be effectively used here for its original objective, without just killing the stream. The final output:

```
fs = require 'fs'
TestTransform = require './test-transform'
inStream = new TestTransform
fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(inStream)
inStream.on 'data', (chunk) ->
  line = chunk.toString()
  process.stdout.write "-->#{line}"
  if line.match /line\.match/g
    inStream.pause()
    f = fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee")
    f.on 'end', ->
      inStream.resume()
    f.pipe(process.stdout)
```

with output:

```
-->fs = require 'fs'
-->TestTransform = require './test-transform'
-->inStream = new TestTransform
-->fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(inStream)
-->inStream.on 'data', (chunk) ->
-->  line = chunk.toString()
-->  process.stdout.write "-->#{line}"
-->  if line.match /line\.match/g
fs = require 'fs'
TestTransform = require './test-transform'
inStream = new TestTransform
fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee").pipe(inStream)
inStream.on 'data', (chunk) ->
  line = chunk.toString()
  process.stdout.write "-->#{line}"
  if line.match /line\.match/g
    inStream.pause()
    f = fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee")
    f.on 'end', ->
      inStream.resume()
    f.pipe(process.stdout)
-->    inStream.pause()
-->    f = fs.createReadStream("./test.coffee")
-->    f.on 'end', ->
-->      inStream.resume()
-->    f.pipe(process.stdout)
-->
```

which was the intended result.